# How to find Laplace transform of a differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

$y′′ + 3y′ + 2y = f$ , $y(0) = 0$ , $y′(0) = 1$ where $f$ is given by

$f(t) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \delta(t−n)$; find a 1-periodic function $y_*$ with $\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty} |y(t)−y_*(t)| = 0$.

I am having trouble with this question. Particularly finding a 1-period function and setting up the question. I would be really grateful for help.

Comment: One way would be to consider the equation on the intervals $[n,n+1)$ and 'translate' the impulse input into an equivalent change in initial conditions. Then look at the resulting $(y(n),y'(n))$, which presumable converge to some value. The behaviour on the interior of the interval $(n,n+1)$ is a generic unforced response.